# If we want to use proof by contradiction, shouldn't we first proof that a statement is either true or false?

Tags: axioms

As an example how this could go wrong "This statement is false"
We could proof this statement by contradiction as follows

Assume the statement is false $\implies$ The statement is false $\implies$ the statement is true. Which is a contradiction, hence the statement must be true.

Obviously, the statement being true leads to equally contradictory results, but in mathematics we I have never seen anyone continue to check also what happends if we assume the statement is true. And if we did, it would not be humanly possible to check all possible consequences of a statement being true.

Is there a mathematical axiom that claims that all statements are either true or false, and how can we be sure that this axiom itself does not lead to contradictions?

Comment: "prove that a statement is either true or false" - what else should a statement be ?

Comment: "This statement is false" is a self-referred statement leading to a paradox.

Comment: If a system can prove a statement AND its negation, it is inconsistent and therefore useless.

Comment: And finally, if a system has at least the power of the peano axioms, we can unfortunately not guarantee its consistency at all (which was shown by Goedel). Gentzen's attempt seems to be a work-around at first sight but it uses transfinite induction which has to be justified.

Comment: Studying logic and the foundations of mathematics will help you to distinguish the notions of *provable* statements and statements that are *true*.  The paradoxes of self-reference have been known since antiquity; the one you mention is typically called the [Liar's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a mathematical axiom that claims that all statements are either true or false?

Yes, it is called [Law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle).
This is always used for the vast majority of mathematics.

> and how can we be sure that this axiom itself does not lead to contradictions?

We can't (provided we start with sufficiently strong axioms such as Peano arithmetic or ZFC).
This is known as Goedel's second incompleteness theorem.

> "This statement is false"

This is a self-referential statement. While this is possible in the english language,
i am not aware of any formulation in classical mathematics of this statement. In my (and probably many other's) opinion this is therefore not a valid example to show that a mathematical statement can be neither true nor false.

Comment: Perfect answer and a good summary of my comments (+1)